# Confusion with the use of と in article

Tags: grammar, particle-と

Im reading this [article](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011584661000/k10011584661000.html) and I don't think I fully understand the use of the **と** in this context. My translation seems off with it being converted to an "and". What is the と really supposed to represent here?

> イスラム教の人がサウジアラビアのメッカ**と**その近くへ祈りに行く「ハッジ」が始まりました
>   My Translation: Hajj has started, which is where Islamic people go to pray at a vicinity and Saudi Arabia's Mecca.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The と means "and".

「メッカ**と**その近く」 = "Mecca **and** its vicinity"

> イスラム教の人がサウジアラビアの**メッカとその近く**へ祈りに行く「ハッジ」が始まりました。
>   Hajj, in which Muslims go to pray in **Mecca and its vicinity** in Saudi Arabia, has started.

Comment: I see, so then the へ covers (I guess I'll call it a noun phrase) サウジアラビアのメッカとその近く as a whole